# Issue with PHP variable type conversion

Tags: php, mysql, bbpress

I am using the following code to show any tag related topics on bbPress search results.

```
<?php
$x = esc_attr( bbp_get_search_terms() );
$y = (string) $x;
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_terms WHERE name=$y";
$tag=$wpdb->get_row($query);
echo $y;
$z= (int) $tag->term_id;
echo do_shortcode("[bbp-single-tag id=$z]");
?>
```

Its not working althoug "echo $y" prints 'analytics'. Everything works fine if I use actual search term 'analytics' instead of $y in the query. Like

```
<?php
$x = esc_attr( bbp_get_search_terms() );
$y = (string) $x;
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_terms WHERE name='analytics'";
$tag=$wpdb->get_row($query);
echo $y;
$z= (int) $tag->term_id;
echo do_shortcode("[bbp-single-tag id=$z]");
?>
```

The name column is of varchar type in Database. What is the mistake here.

Comment: I'm confused. What's the actual issue?

Comment: `name=analytics?` do you have a column called `analytics` and a column called `name` in your `wp_terms` table?

Comment: I have a column called name which is varchar type. A user searches for a term, e.g. analytics. This term is then searched in wp_terms database and if matched the corresponding term_id is used in the shortcode to display some results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what your asking but try to add quotes around the variable

```
"SELECT * FROM wp_terms WHERE name='$y'";
                                   ^  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using single quotes in your do_shortcode parameter... the entire thing is interpreted as a string.  Use double quotes, and the variable will be interpolated.

```
echo do_shortcode("[bbp-single-tag id=$z]");
```

Comment: Thanks I have modified the code and issue with this line is solved. But, I still have the issue with query string. I have edited the question.